# How to use git in Linux from Jenkins on windows master and linux slave?

Tags: linux, git, jenkins

I have a job in Jenkins that runs on Linux. jenkins is running on a windows master and this job is on linux slave server (Unix slave, version 3.7), I want to use git in linux throw jenkins pipline job so I'm using:

> git branch: '${my_branch}', url:......

but seems like it's trying to call git from windows so I'm getting this error:

> Cloning repository http://....
>
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe init /home/jenkins/workspace/
>
> ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
>
> /home/jenkins/workspace/compiler/llvm/atheel_driver_linux/MY_GIT # timeout=10

why its calling c:\ ? (instead of linux folders) Any help? I have run it on a node that tuns in linux:

```
node ('sdt-srv2-linux') { ... }
```

Please help

Comment: I have jsut found an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223071/jenkins-path-to-git-windows-master-linux-slave thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins path to git Windows master / Linux slave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223071/jenkins-path-to-git-windows-master-linux-slave)